# AngularJS Karma Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

Just messing around with the moviedb api and am trying to write a test for my navigateGenre function but I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Here is the spec and controller code:

Spec:

```
describe('Genre List Controller', function(){
    var ctrl, scope;

    beforeEach(module('MovieFinder'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $route, $rootScope, _$location_, _GenreListFactory_){
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var $location = _$location_;
        var GenreListFactory = _GenreListFactory_;

        $route.current = {
            params: {
                genreId: 18
            }
        };

        ctrl = $controller('GenreListCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            $location: $location,
            GenreListFactory: GenreListFactory,
            $route: $route
        });
    }));

    fit('should route to correct genre when navigateGenre() is called',
    inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope, $route, $location){
        $httpBackend.expect('JSONP', 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').respond(200);
        $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'js/genre-detail/genre-detail.html').respond(200);

        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            $location.path('/genre/18');
        });

        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            scope.navigateGenre();
        });

        expect($route.current.originalPath).toBe('/genre/:genreId');
        expect($route.current.params.genreId).toBe();

    }));
});
```

Controller:

```
MovieFinder
    .controller('GenreListCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$location', 'GenreListFactory', function($scope, $route, $location, GenreListFactory){
        GenreListFactory().then(function(genres){
            console.log('GenreListCtrl', genres);
            $scope.test = 'test';
            $scope.genreList = [{id: null, name: 'Select a Genre'}];
            genres.data.genres.forEach(function(genre){
                //console.log(genre.name);
                $scope.genreList.push(genre);
            });
            $scope.selectedGenre = $scope.genreList[0];
        });
        $scope.navigateGenre = function(){
            if($scope.selectedGenre.id !== null){
                $location.path('genre/' + $scope.selectedGenre.id);
                $scope.selectedGenre = $scope.genreList[0];
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Let me know if I need to include anything.

Comment: As far as i can notice.
You should try to resolve the promise with some mock data first then only your $scope.genreList and $scope.selectedGenre will get initialized. You are calling the navigationGenre function but $scope.selectedGenre is not getting initialized anywhere.

Comment: @Diljohn5741 thanks for the advice I will try that and see if I can get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was finally able to get this thing working.
What I did was move the `$scope.genreList and $scope.selectedGenre` out of the .then().
The `$httpBackend.expect` is set up to respond with a 200 but if we don't simulate a deferred promise and resolve it the `.then` will never trigger.

Here is the refactored code:

Controller:

```
MovieFinder
    .controller('GenreListCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$location', 'GenreListFactory', function($scope, $route, $location, GenreListFactory){
        $scope.genreList = [{id: null, name: 'Select a Genre'}];
        $scope.selectedGenre = $scope.genreList[0];

        GenreListFactory().then(function(genres){
            console.log('GenreListCtrl', genres);
            $scope.test = 'test';
            genres.data.genres.forEach(function(genre){
                //console.log(genre.name);
                $scope.genreList.push(genre);
            });
            console.log('genreList', $scope.genreList);
        });
        console.log('genreList', $scope.genreList);
        $scope.navigateGenre = function(){
            if($scope.selectedGenre.id !== null){
                $location.path('genre/' + $scope.selectedGenre.id);
                $scope.selectedGenre = $scope.genreList[0];
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Spec:

```
describe('Genre List Controller', function(){
        var ctrl, scope;

        beforeEach(module('MovieFinder'));

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $route, $rootScope, _$location_, _GenreListFactory_){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            var $location = _$location_;
            var GenreListFactory = _GenreListFactory_;

            $route.current = {
                params: {
                    genreId: 18
                }
            };

            scope.selectedGenre = {
                id: 80,
                name: 'Crime'
            };

            ctrl = $controller('GenreListCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                $location: $location,
                GenreListFactory: GenreListFactory,
                $route: $route
            });
        }));

        it('should route to correct genre when navigateGenre() is called',
        inject(function($httpBackend, $rootScope, $route, $location){
            $httpBackend.expect('JSONP', 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=990ba45b90f56c57b4e00a54fc773d8c&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').respond(200);
            $httpBackend.expect('GET', 'js/genre-detail/genre-detail.html').respond(200);

            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                $location.path('/genre/18');
            });

            $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                /*scope.selectedGenre.id = 80;*/
                scope.navigateGenre();
            });

            expect($route.current.params.genreId).toBe('18');
            expect(scope.selectedGenre.id).toBe(null);

        }));
    });
```